# How to render events on fullcalendar agendaweek view-Symfony 3

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, fullcalendar

I try to render events on my fullcalendar agendaweek view. For the month view, it's ok! but when i see on view week, events are not here??? Even if, when i create a new event, i set each events with a start and end date with this format : dd-mm-yyyy hh:ii

if somebody can help me, i post my controler:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request){
  //....//
  if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $title = $form->get('title')->getData();
    $start = new \DateTime($form->get('startDate')->getData());
    $end = new \DateTime($form->get('endDate')->getData());

    $event = new CalendarEvent();
    $event->setTitle($title);
    $event->setStartDate($start);
    $event->setEndDate($end);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($event);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('...path...'));
  }
  //.....//
}
```

And this is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev, next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay'
    },
    timezone: ('Europe/London'),
    businessHours: {
        start: '09:00',
        end: '18:30',
        dow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    },
    allDaySlot: true,
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    lazyFetching: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    selectable: true,
    timeFormat: {
        agenda: 'h:mmt',
        '': 'h:mmt'
    },
    editable: true,
    eventDurationEditable: true,
    events: 'http://localhost/ligne_rh/web/app_dev.php/admin/accueil/calendar',

  });
});
```

Comment: the answer below is correct re the time format. If you still have any other problems, please provide some debugging info - e.g. any errors that occur in your browser's console window or network tools, and a sample of the JSON event output, if required.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Now I have correctly set the time format like this : 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'...but my events are always not on the week view?? no errors in the browser's console window...And my JSON data look like this :id 1
title "test"
start "2017-08-01T18:00:00"
end "2017-08-01T20:00:00"
allDay true
editable true
startEditable true
durationEditable true
overlap true
url ""
backgroundColor ""
textColor ""
className ""
rendering ""
constraint 1
source ""
color ""

Comment: but they show up in month view, yes? or No? Your events in that example are set for 1st August. Obvious question but...have you changed the week view to show that date? By default it will use today's date, 31st August. 1st August is far in the past to be in the current week, as I'm sure you realise.

Comment: :-) thank you! Effectively, my date example was for the 1st August. I have other event example with today's date. Despite this, my events are not display on the week view but they show up in month view! any idea??

Comment: I can show them on the top of the week view (allday raw),  I can drag and drop them but when refresh the browser's windows, they disppear...any idea??

Comment: ah yes I hadn't spotted you set allDay to true. If you set allDay to true, it ignores the timing part of the start/end times, and shows them in the allDay section of the calendar. set allDay false if you don't want that behaviour. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/ for a description of the allDay property.

Comment: as for why they disappear / move back to their original location when you refresh the page, well, when you refresh a web page, as I'm sure you know, all changes on the old page are lost unless you save those changes somewhere, like to your database. HTTP requests are stateless. fullCalendar just refreshes the data from the server, as if the previous version of the page (and your dragging/dropping actions) had never existed.

Comment: Ok!! Thank you for those comments. unfortunately, after set allDaySlot to false... always nothing...

Comment: Also don't forget when you refresh the page it also resets the date in the view to today's date, so you have to scroll back through to the relevant week. But failing that, if there are no errors in the console, and you can verify via the browser's network tab that the ajax requests are being made, and a valid JSON response (array of events) is being returned which fullCalendar can understand, then it's really quite difficult to say why you can't see anything. All the pieces seem to be in place. So either what you're telling me is not correct, or there's something else interfering.

Comment: Thank you for all!! you are great!! I need to keep probing... if you have any js example...??

Comment: example of what, exactly? On the face of it, nothing is wrong with your code or your data. So like I said, either what you've told me is incorrect, or there's some other vital detail you have omitted which is interfering with your calendar code.

Comment: Thank you for your help!!:-)

Comment: ok!!!! it's work!!! thank you!!thank you!!!!

Comment: that's great. Out of interest, what did you do to solve it?

Comment: My protected allDay attribute was define to true in my event class!!! it was very stupid!! thank you very much for all!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your start and end time need a slightly different format from what we'd usually use for PHP / MySQL. It should look like this:

> 2017-09-01T23:59

This is as per the [Moment](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/) time specification. You may also want to have a thorough read of the details of the rest of the [Event Object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) to be sure there's nothing else odd that applies to your use case.

Comment: Thank you for you answer!! Now i know why it's doesnt work!! Do you have a link or un example to fullcalendar js file?? because i dont know how to correctly set to this time format?? :-)